# Date Picker alert Dialog

Tags: android, datepicker

When i am running my code in android 3.2 and android 4.0.3, it shows different date pickers..i want date picker as a wheeler like 1st image..i know 2.3.3 shows old pickers..But i don't know why i am getting older one in 4.0.3 which is giving new in 3.2. It happened same with Number Picker also.

here is my code:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        if (picker == 1) {
            final long lDate = mDay;
            dateStart.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
            dateStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
            dateStart.set(Calendar.DATE, mDay);
            Log.d("startdate", "" + dateStart);
            if (lDate != -1) {
                UpdateStartDateTimeView();

                return;
            }

        }


        updateDisplay();
    }
};
```

[image: This i got in 3.2]
[image: This i got in 4.0.3]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the native picker, automatically Android will choose the corresponding to the current version. You can only ensure that a unique dialog is presented regardless Android version by creating a custom Dialog. Thus, you need to see if the unique picker worths the effort of designing a custom one..

Comment: i want native picker only.i dont want custom picker..my problem is i am getting older picker rather tha its native picker...see the 1st pic..it is android 4.0.3..its native is different but i am getting older picker ...but in android it calls correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The DatePickerDialog is having a constructor which accepts a theme

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Just update ur code with

for light holo theme

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, 
new DateListener(v), mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
```

or

for dark holo theme

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo__Dialog_NoActionBar, 
new DateListener(v), mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you're getting an old dialog style in Andoid version above 4. I had this problem when I set **STYLE_NO_FRAME** for dialog fragment. In this case date picker has always old design, and I don't know why it is so. If you want to get always modern UI, be sure you set **STYLE_NORMAL** to your dialog fragment. For do this you need to add following line in OnCreate callback method of the dialog fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, 0);
}
```